# jqm slider stop event not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

I am trying to build a JQM page with a toggle/flip slider that shows/hides txt box based on slider position.
Please see JSfiddle [test page](http://jsfiddle.net/GlynLewis/aYdua/).

HTML -

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <label>JQM Slider Toggle test</label>
</div>
<div data-role="container">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="OnFront">Device Location:</label>
        <select name="OnFront" id="OnFront" data-role="slider" data-theme="b">
            <option value="true">Front</option>
            <option value="false">Rear</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="DeviceOnFront">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="FrontPosId">Front Position</label>
            <input type="text" id="FrontPosId" class="input_txt"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="DeviceOnRear" hidden="hidden">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="RearPosId">Rear Position</label>
            <input type="text" id="RearPosId" class="input_txt"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <label>Glyn Lewis</label>
</div>
```

JS -

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').bind('pageinit', function () {

// debug test to see if events are firing ???
 $("#OnFront").on("start", function () {
     alert("User has started sliding my-slider!");
 });

$("#OnFront").on("stop", function (event) {
     var value = event.target.value;
     alert("User has finished sliding my slider, its value is: " + value);
 });

 // code for changing which txt box is shown
 // based on toggle/flip switch
 $("#OnFront").on("stop", function (event) {
     var value = event.target.value;
     if (value == true) {
         $("#DeviceOnFront").show();
         $("#DeviceOnRear").hide();
     } else {
         $("#DeviceOnFront").hide();
         $("#DeviceOnRear").show();
     };
 });
```

};

I am unable to get the slider "stop" event to fire ??

Any pointers would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution made from your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AWyXq/

You had few error's. Events sliderstop and sliderstart don't exist:

```
 $("#OnFront").on("sliderstart", function () {
     alert("User has started sliding my-slider!");
 });
```

their correct names are **slidestart** and **slidestop**:

```
$('#OnFront').on('slidestart', function(){    
     console.log('Start');
});
```

Comment: Magic, many thanks for your help and guidance... I also note you changed the "pageinit" to $(document).on('pagebeforeshow',... can you please explain the reason .

Comment: The fiddle works correctly however I still have an issue with my code.  The event is firing and being trapped by my code, I see it in the log however the elements are not toggling ? the first time through the correct flip happens but after that the screen is not updated even though the javascript is being hit ???

Comment: Just created simple html page with code from fiddle and that also works correctly.

Must be something to do with the rest of the Site... which is MVC4 web application that I am trying to "mobalise" with JQM. on this site the event fires, the javascript is hit but the elements on the page are only ever updated once ??? Has anyone ever seen this behavior before ??? as I am learning at this time any help or pointers please

Comment: Finally spotted my mistake:
I had **value === true** when I should have had 
**value === "true"**